# How prove the uniqueness of the primary descomposition for abelians finite groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ a abelian group of order $n>1$ and let $n=p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\cdots p_k^{\alpha_k}$ your unique descomposition in distinct prime factors. Then $$ G \cong A_1 \times A_2 \times \cdots \times A_k$$ where $|A_i|=p_i^{\alpha_i}$.Prove that this descomposition is unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A_i=\{x\in G | p^{\alpha_{i}}x=0\}$.

Answer (score 0):

$A_i$ is the $p_i$-Sylow subgroup of $G$.